# Install TinyMCE using Vite In Laravel

Tags: laravel, tinymce, vite, tinymce-plugins, laravel-vite

How can I install TinyMCE using Vite in Laravel? I tried changing to Laravel Mix, but for some reason, it didn't work at all. So, I kind of gave up on that for now. I searched for ways to install TinyMCE, but I didn't find anything or any instructions on how to do that. I found their installation documentation, but it was using Laravel Mix.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/laravel-composer-install/